# Access TextBlock.Text Inside a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, button

I have a set of `Buttons` that are styled as so;

```
<Button x:Name="rhsNavButton1">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

I want to loop through these `Buttons` and modify the `TextBlock.Text` inside them. So far I have done something like this;

```
int j = 11;
foreach (UIElement control in RHSNavButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        var tb = ((control as Button).Content).Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
        tb.Text = buttonNames.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        j++;
    }
}
```

But I am having no luck in accessing the `TextBlock` (`NullException`). How can I access the `Textblock's` text property when it inside the `Button` programtically?

Comment: I think the problem is `((control as Button).Content).Children` you probably  need to have this  `((control as Button).Content) as TextBlock)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `var tb = ((control as Button).Content  as TextBlock);` instead of `(control as Button).Content).Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();`

```
int j = 11;
foreach (UIElement control in RHSNavButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        var tb = ((control as Button).Content  as TextBlock);
        tb.Text = buttonNames.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        j++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `TextBlock` is placed inside your button as content directly and you don't use any [`Container Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx) like `StackPanel` you don't need to use `Children`. Just use this:

```
int j = 11;
foreach (UIElement control in RHSNavButtonGrid.Children)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        var tb = ((control as Button).Content) as TextBlock;
        tb.Text = buttonNames.Rows[j][0].ToString();
        j++;
    }
}
```